# Is it possible to align x axis title to a value of the axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a tibble and a simple scatterplot:

```
p <- tibble(
       x = rnorm(50, 1),
       y = rnorm(50, 10)
     )

ggplot(p, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

I get something like this:

[image]

I would like to align (center, left, right, as the case may be) the title of the x-axis - here rather blandly *x* - with a specific value on the axis, say the off-center *0* in this case. Is there a way to do that declaratively, without having to resort to the dumb (as in "free of context") trial-and-error `element_text(hjust=??)`. The `??` are rather appropriate here because every value is a result of experimentation (my screen and PDF export in RStudio **never** agree on quite some plot elements). Any change in the data or the dimensions of the rendering may (or may not) invalidate the `hjust` value and I am looking for a solution that graciously repositions itself, much like the axes do.

---

Following the suggestions in the comments by @tjebo I dug a little deeper into the coordinate spaces. `hjust = 0.0` and `hjust = 1.0` clearly align the label with the Cartesian coordinate system extent (but magically left-aligned and right-aligned, respectively) so when I set specific limits, calculation of the exact value of `hjust` is straightforward (aiming for *0* and `hjust = (0 - -1.5) / (3.5 - -1.5) = 0.3`):

```
ggplot(p, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(8, 12.5), xlim = c(-1.5, 3.5), expand=FALSE) + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.3))
```

This gives an acceptable result for a label like *x*, but for longer labels the alignment is off again:

```
ggplot(p %>% mutate(`Longer X label` = x), aes(x = `Longer X label`, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(8, 12.5), xlim = c(-1.5, 3.5), expand=FALSE) + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.3))
```

Any further suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Your ggplot function should rather be `ggplot(p, aes(x, y))` (remove the = sign).

Comment: @tjebo Interesting approach, but wouldn't this introduce the problem of shifting offsets if y values change? If a point (x,y)=(0,1000) is added, then the coordinate space would change and thus the distance of the axis title to the axis itself.

Comment: Hi @tjebo, I updated my question on the basis of your suggestions. Have another look if you like

Answer (score 2):

I still think you will fair better and easier with custom annotation. There are typically two ways to do that. Either direct labelling with a text layer (for single labels I prefer `annotate(geom = "text")`, or you create a separate plot and stitch both together, e.g. with patchwork.

The biggest challenge is the positioning in y dimension. For this I typically take a semi-automatic approach where I only need to define one constant, and set the coordinates relative to the data range, so changes in range should in theory not matter much. (they still do a bit, because the panel dimensions also change). Below showing examples of exact label positioning for two different data ranges (using the same constant for both)

```r
library(tidyverse)
# I only need patchwork for demo purpose, it is not required for the answer
library(patchwork)

p <- tibble( x = rnorm(50, 1), y = rnorm(50, 10))
p1 <- tibble( x = rnorm(50, 1), y = 100*rnorm(50, 10))
## I like to define constants outside my ggplot call
y_fac <- .1
mylab <- "longer_label"
x_demo <- c(-1, 2)

demo_fct <- function(df, x) {map(x_demo,~{
  ## I like to define constants outside my ggplot call
  ylims <- range(df$y)
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ## set hjust = 0 for full positioning control
  annotate(geom = "text", x = ., y = min(ylims) - y_fac*mean(ylims),
           label = mylab, hjust = 0) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = ylims, clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(b = .5, unit = "in")) +
  labs(x = NULL)
})
}

demo_fct(p, x_demo) %>% wrap_plots() + plot_annotation(title = "demo 1, label at x = -1 and x = 2")
```

[image]

```r
demo_fct(p1, x_demo) %>% wrap_plots() + plot_annotation(title = "demo 2 - different data range")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: one could optimise this approach and make the constant change with the range. But I guess that might be slight overkill

Answer (score 2):

Another option (different enough hopefully to justify the second answer) is as already mentioned to create the annotation as a separate plot. This removes the range problem. I like {patchwork} for this.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p <- tibble( x = rnorm(50, 1), y = rnorm(50, 10))
p1 <- tibble( x = rnorm(50, 1), y = 100*rnorm(50, 10))

## I like to define constants outside my ggplot call
mylab <- "longer_label"
x_demo <- c(-1, 2)

demo_fct <- function(p){
p1 <- ggplot(p, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin())

p2 <- ggplot(p, aes(x, y)) +
  ## you need that for your correct alignment with the first plot
  geom_blank() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = x_demo, y = 1,
           label = mylab, hjust = 0) +
  theme_void() +
  # you need that for those annoying margin reasons
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") 

p1 / p2 + plot_layout(heights = c(1, .05))
}

demo_fct(p) + plot_annotation(title = "demo1 with x at -1 and 2")
```

[image]

```r
demo_fct(p1) + plot_annotation(title = "demo2 with larger data range")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>